# estoy elaborando un pequeño programa que me lea 4 datos de entrada pero este solo lee los primeros 3 y el último solo se imprime

Tags: java, entrada, scanner

Este programa por el momento solo pide  4 datos al  usuario, el problema esta en que solo lee los primeros 3 y el ultimo solo lo imprime el texto apenas empiezo con esta tecnología, me seria de mucha ayuda poder orientarme.

```
package formato;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Formato {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);   
    System.out.println("BIENVENIDOS A ABC");
    String lugar = "";
    String t;
    String autores = "";
    String editorial = "";
    int año   = 0;

    System.out.println("Autores:"); autores = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("titulo del libro:"); t = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("año de la publicación:");  año = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("lugar de la publicación: "); lugar = input.nextLine();
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seguramente puedas encontrar información más detallada sobre el tema si buscas(Lo digo porque mis conocimientos son limnitados), pero, en resumen, el caso es que cuando ingresas un numero por consola realmente ingresas un numero y un salto de linea (cuando le das al enter). Podriamos pensar que el enter es "confirmación de entrada" pero no es asi, es un caracter y como tal, si tienes un nextLine a continuación, lo tomará como su entrada. Una solución pasaría por invertir las entradas (pedir primero todas las cadenas, para a continuación todos los números). Otra, podría ser coger todos los datos como cadenas, y luego hacer los casteos necesarios y por último (aunque nunca me convenció del todo, pero al parecer asi es como se hace) es agregar una lectura de linea extra entre un nextInt y un nextLine, sin almacenamiento de dato, es decir:

```
package formato;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Formato {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);   
    System.out.println("BIENVENIDOS A ABC");
    String lugar = "";
    String t;
    String autores = "";
    String editorial = "";
    int año   = 0;

    System.out.println("Autores:"); autores = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("titulo del libro:"); t = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("año de la publicación:");  año = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("lugar de la publicación: "); lugar = input.nextLine();
    
  }
}
```